# Dispatch and inheritance (static vs. dynamic types)

Tags: types, compiler-construction

So in my compilers class we looked at the code

```
p : Point;
p <- new ColorPoint;
```

Here p is being declared as a Point, but is assigned a ColorPoint object, and ColorPoint is a subclass of Point.

The instructor said that p has static type Point, but it has dynamic type ColorPoint.  And he said that's because the compiler doesn't know p is a ColorPoint at compile time, and it only finds out about that at runtime.  Why is that?  Can't the compiler see that p is being assigned a ColorPoint object?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in this context it can, but what if you had

```
p : Point;
p <- new ColorPoint;
// some statements that operate on p
p <- new BlackAndWhitePoint;
// some more statements that operate on p
```

Often, the compiler is not able to infer the whole context where a variable is used so it must go by the declared type.